# Making a very basic binary tree in Scala

Tags: scala, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to make a very simple binary tree in Scala for data storage and traversal.

Right now I have:

```
trait Tree
case class Node(left: Tree, value: String, right: Tree) extends Tree
```

My questions:

1. How can I also include a pointer to a parent?
2. Can I have left and right point to null in any way? Or the parent pointer for the root node?
3. How can I actually traverse the tree?
4. Is it easy to update the values of a node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Not with immutable case classes. It is a circular dependency: you need the parent to create the children, but you also need the children to create the parent. On the other hand most tree traversal algorithms don't really need the parent as the parent is usually on the stack or can be stored somewhere.
2. Yes, we usually represent these with a singleton instance (`object`) of a trait:

   ```
   case object EmptyNode extends Tree
   ```
3. There are a lot of algorithms out there, Breadth First Search and Depth First Search are the most common. It is a good exercise to implement them. But a bit of help on the Scala side, we usually pattern match on the `left` and `right` to see what we need to do next:

   ```
   tree: Tree match {
     case EmptyNode => // do nothing, return, etc.
     case Node(left, value, right) =>
       // Do inorder, preorder, postorder operation order
       // You will also probably be processing left and right as well
   }
   ```
4. No, your guess is right that using immutable case classes in a tree is quite hard to update, because if you update a leaf node then you must recreate everything above it. There are so called Lenses and Lens libraries that can help you with this, although they may be a bit more advanced. One popular one in Scala is [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle).

---

It seems like you are just starting with programming or new to Scala so I would recommend using `var`-s instead of `val`s:

```
case class Node(var left: Tree, var value: String, var right: Tree) extends Tree
```

Also if your traits are sealed (`sealed trait Tree`) then the compiler will tell you if you didn't handle one of the subtypes in a pattern match.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments start working with this:

```
sealed trait Tree
case class Node(var left: Tree, var value: String, var right: Tree, var parent: Tree) extends Tree
case object EmptyNode extends Tree
```

Comment: Yes, by default when you defined `Node` then `left`, `value`, `right` are all defined as `val`-s which means you can not update them. If you would like mutable then write `var` in front of them as I did in the last part of my answer. After that you can freely update attributes whenever.

Comment: Yep, looks good and compiles! Good luck! (Update: Maybe add `sealed` in front of `trait Tree`, as I mentioned the compiler will help and catch bugs for you).

Comment: Now if I wanted to add a child to what I have so far, do I do myTree.left = Node(whatever)?

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to try this out yourself! :) I won't be here all night checking your code :D